# Log format not recognized

Tags: django, logging, pycharm

I'm using pycharm on windows when i was using that on Linux everything was fine

I'm parsing info from my loggers into my model db but for some reason i guess bcs log format for somehow not recognized in pycharm i got this in my model `РџРµСЂСЃРѕРЅР°Р»СЊРЅС‹Р№ РєРѕРјРїСЊСЋС‚РµСЂ`

UTF-8 in my log files works good I mean i have russian letters and thats what i need but when i parse them with this:

```
    with open('loggers/log_user_activity/user_activity.log', 'r') as filelog:
        for i_line in filelog.readlines():
            if i_line.startswith('INFO') and len(i_line.split()) == 9:
```

I got this in console:

`INFO 2023-04-24 16:20:19,672 k.nefedov 127.0.0.1 РџРµСЂСЃРѕРЅР°Р»СЊРЅС‹Р№_РєРѕРјРїСЊСЋС‚РµСЂ Р—Р°С€С‘Р»_РЅР°_СЃР°Р№С‚ - -`

Log settings in pycharm:
[image]